# .htaccess HTTP to HTTPS but showing subfolder

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I am using following rule of .htaccess to redirect site from http to https.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

But my site code is placed under folder Testversion. So when I add this rule in .htaccess file, my url becomes "https://abcd.com/Testversion" instead of "https://abcd.com"

Any one knows how I can skip Testversion folder name ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference: mod\_rewrite, URL rewriting and "pretty links" explained](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563772/reference-mod-rewrite-url-rewriting-and-pretty-links-explained)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `.htaccess` is placed inside a subdirectory then you can use:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```

i.e. capture relative URI (from current directory) from `RewriteRule` and use it in the target.